# Cypress - A modal which is supposed to be visible after clicking an element is not opening up after the click

Tags: cypress, el

I am trying to validate a popup modal after clicking on an element.
During the test run, the click command is successfully completed but the modal is not visible.

I stopped running the test and then tried to click the element manually - even now the modal is not opened up!!

Tried click({ force: true }) and also the locators are correct.

//code

```
  cy.get(locator for opening up the modal).click() // click is done
  cy.get(locator for modal header).should('be.visible') // modal is not visible
```

Comment: Add the HTML of your element.

Comment: It was because of cypress running test under an iframe. Added the below code on visiting URL and it works now-> use the [link](https://www.eliostruyf.com/tests-running-iframe-cypress-e2e-tests/) for more info.                                                                  `cy.visit(config.pageUrl, {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    // Let the child think it runs in the parent
    win["parent"] = win;
  }
});`